# read single value HDF5 C++

Tags: c++, hdf5

**Situation:**

I try to read a value from a `.hdf5` file.

**System:**

- Windows 7 (64bit)
- c++ (MSVC17 64bit)
- Qt Creator (5.10.1)
- HDF5 (1.8.15)

**My Code:**

```
//File Path
hid_t H5_hid_RESULTS = H5Fcreate (V_FIn_HDF5_Path.absoluteFilePath().toUtf8().constData(), H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

//Status (Error Output?)
herr_t status;

//read dataset "heigth"
int32_t     heigth[1];
hid_t       H5_hid_heigth = H5Dopen1(H5_hid_RESULTS, "heigth");
status = H5Dread(H5_hid_heigth, H5T_NATIVE_INT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, heigth);
qDebug() << "heigth" << heigth[0];
status = H5Dclose(H5_hid_heigth);

//Close: file
status = H5Fclose (H5_hid_RESULTS);
```

**The target** .hdf5 file (in viewer):

[image: Screenshot]

**Result:**

The qDebug prints a random number (example: 104610208) instead of the expected 512.

**Questions:**

- Why does this happen?
- What should I change to read ints, floats, etc? With 2D selfmade arrays it is working, but not with single values in the .hdf5 i need to read.

**What I tried:**

- I tried to use `int[1]` instead of `int32_t[1]`: same result.
- I tried to use `int` instead of i`nt32_t[1]`: 
  `D:\...\xyz.cpp:47: Error: C2664: "herr_t H5Dread(hid_t,hid_t,hid_t,hid_t,hid_t,void *)" : Conversion from argument 6 from "int" to "void *" not possible`
- I tried to use `int*` instead of `int32_t[1]`: `0x7fe00000001` i guess the adress of the value. If i try to print `*heigth` instead of `heigth`, it crashes when function is called
- I tried some other formats and cast, but without effort.
- I tried passing `"/heigth"` instead of `"heigth"`: same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a totaly diffrent but very simple approach inspired by this [example](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/readdata_8cpp-example.html) here. Basicly the same code as in the link but very much simplified so newbies to c++ and HDF5 can understand it:

```
//open file (My path is zensored, project from work)
const H5std_string  H5_Path_Results("C:/.../results.hdf5");
H5File              H5_File_Results(H5_Path_Results, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);

//open set
const H5std_string  H5_Nam_Height("height");
DataSet             H5_Set_Height = H5_File_Results.openDataSet(H5_Nam_Height);

//read set
int                 height[1];
H5_Set_Height.read(height, PredType::NATIVE_INT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL);
qDebug() << height[0];

//close set
H5_Set_Height.close();

//close file
H5_File_Results.close();
```

This gives the 512 i wanted to read as output.

Of course `#include <hdf5.h>` and `#include <H5Cpp.h>` are needed, the libraries must be added to the project and the `.hdf5` file must exist.

Answer (score 0):

As the file viewer indicates, you data type for you 512 is `H5T_NATIVE_INT32` and not `H5T_NATIVE_INT`. In other words, you are trying to read in a 64bit integer where there is only a 32 bit integer. This should work for you:

```
status = H5Dread(H5_hid_heigth, H5T_NATIVE_INT32, 
                 H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, heigth);
```